# How to use Python regex to substitute a row break dependent on line beginnings

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which consists of a number of stacked files, where the original files are of the format: Two header lines starting with K: or M: in any order, and 
then a indefinite number of lines of (ASCII) text of any length (but never starting with the K: or M: headers):
K:cccc...
M:cccc...
cccc..
ccc..
..
..
K:cccc...
M:cccc...
cccc..
ccc..
..
..
M:cccc...
K:cccc...
cccc..
ccc..
..
..
etc

c is any ASCII char, so an arbitrary line `cccc...` above could be something like: 
        &/dm%hdma76H?',,,3dd"@

Observe the switch of M/K-order in the last file. What I need to do is to put in an extra \n between the original files, like so:
K:cccc...
M:cccc...
cccc..
ccc..
..
..

K:cccc...
M:cccc...
cccc..
ccc..
..
..
etc

This is obviously an easy task generally, but I want to do it with regex. The reason is that this task is one of many things
I do to this file, and in all other cases regex is used without problems. And just of curiosity of course!

This is what I have tried in Python without success:

```
re.sub('(?<!^[KM]:)(.+)(\n)(?=^[KM]:)','\g<1>\n\n',file,flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

The idea is simple: When you get a line not starting with K: or M: followed by a line starting with an K: or an M: then I put in an extra \n. To do that 
I need to run in multiline. What happens instead is that \n is inserted between the header lines as well.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Instead of using "K or M then ':'" (?=^[KM]:) I would use "K: or M:". Same thing for the "not".

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\n((?:[KM]:.*\n?){2})', r'\n\n\1', file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for a block of two lines beginning with `K` or `M`, and add a newline before :

```
import re

text = """K:cccc...<br>
M:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>
K:cccc...<br>
M:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>
M:cccc...<br>
K:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>
etc"""

pattern = re.compile('((^[KM].*\n){2})', re.MULTILINE)
print re.sub(pattern,r'\n\1',text)
```

It outputs :

```
K:cccc...<br>
M:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>

K:cccc...<br>
M:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>

M:cccc...<br>
K:cccc...<br>
cccc..<br>
cccc..<br>
..<br>
..<br>
etc
```

Note that a newline will be added to the first line as well (I couldn't find a way to display it in SO block.)

Comment: @DJL : Is the newline on first line desired?

Comment: Well, actually I am going to split on empty lines and thus recover the original files, but right now I can't say how the split implementation is going to treat the first empty line - if it is going to give me an extra empty "file" or not. But this is a minor problem :)

Comment: @DJL: Also, the last block should have a newline at the end.